# Virtual host is redirect to localhost

Tags: apache, xampp

I have problem to create virtual host with XAMMP. The virtual host always redirect to localhost. For example when I type mysite.local will redirect to localhost/mysite. Below is my hosts and apache config:

1. etc/hosts

   ```
   127.0.0.1       localhost
   255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
   ::1             localhost
   fe80::1%lo0     localhost
   127.0.0.1       mysite.local
   ```
2. /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

   ```
   NameVirtualHost *:80
   # localhost
   <VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName localhost
     DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs"
   </VirtualHost> 
   <VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName mysite.local
     ServerAlias mysite.local *.lancome.local
     DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/mysite"
     <Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/mysite">
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes execCGI
       AllowOverride All
       Require all granted
     </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>
   ```

Comment: have `.htaccess` file inside `/mysite` folder?

Comment: yes I have .htaccess inside /mysite folder. This is magento 2 project

Comment: @Ben did you have a followup to why you asked about .htaccess? I'm having this issue also and the answer would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

1) D:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/webshop_moscow/trunk"
 ServerName bos.webshop.local
 <Directory "D:/xampp/htdocs/webshop_moscow/trunk">
  # Order allow,deny
  # Allow from all
  Require all granted
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

2) C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc

```
127.0.0.1       bos.webshop.local
```

Comment: this seems like a Microsoft Windows setup up not a OP macOS